# How to monitor network interface utilization correctly with Telegraf, InfluxDB, & Grafana?

Tags: networking, monitoring, grafana

I have Telegraf installed on a server and it contains the following network configuration:

```
[[inputs.net]]
  interfaces = ["eth0"]
```

This feeds the following metrics into InfluxDB:

`bytes_recv`, `bytes_sent`, `drop_in`, `drop_out`, `err_in`, `err_out`, `icmp_inaddrmaskreps`, `icmp_inaddrmasks`, `icmp_incsumerrors`, `icmp_indestunreachs`, `icmp_inechoreps`, `icmp_inechos`, `icmp_inerrors`, `icmp_inmsgs`, `icmp_inparmprobs`, `icmp_inredirects`, `icmp_insrcquenchs`, `icmp_intimeexcds`, `icmp_intimestampreps`, `icmp_intimestamps`, `icmp_outaddrmaskreps`, `icmp_outaddrmasks`, `icmp_outdestunreachs`, `icmp_outechoreps`, `icmp_outechos`, `icmp_outerrors`, `icmp_outmsgs`, `icmp_outparmprobs`, `icmp_outredirects`, `icmp_outsrcquenchs`, `icmp_outtimeexcds`, `icmp_outtimestampreps`, `icmp_outtimestamps`, `ip_defaultttl`, `ip_forwarding`, `ip_forwdatagrams`, `ip_fragcreates`, `ip_fragfails`, `ip_fragoks`, `ip_inaddrerrors`, `ip_indelivers`, `ip_indiscards`, `ip_inhdrerrors`, `ip_inreceives`, `ip_inunknownprotos`, `ip_outdiscards`, `ip_outnoroutes`, `ip_outrequests`, `ip_reasmfails`, `ip_reasmoks`, `ip_reasmreqds`, `ip_reasmtimeout`, `packets_recv`, `packets_sent`, `tcp_activeopens`, `tcp_attemptfails`, `tcp_currestab`, `tcp_estabresets`, `tcp_incsumerrors`, `tcp_inerrs`, `tcp_insegs`, `tcp_maxconn`, `tcp_outrsts`, `tcp_outsegs`, `tcp_passiveopens`, `tcp_retranssegs`, `tcp_rtoalgorithm`, `tcp_rtomax`, `tcp_rtomin`, `udp_ignoredmulti`, `udp_incsumerrors`, `udp_indatagrams`, `udp_inerrors`, `udp_noports`, `udp_outdatagrams`, `udp_rcvbuferrors`, `udp_sndbuferrors`, `udplite_ignoredmulti`, `udplite_incsumerrors`, `udplite_indatagrams`, `udplite_inerrors`, `udplite_noports`, `udplite_outdatagrams`, `udplite_rcvbuferrors`, `udplite_sndbuferrors`

I then created a panel in Grafana with the following query:

```
SELECT
  derivative(sum("bytes_sent"), 1s) AS "up",,
  derivative(sum("bytes_recv"), 1s) AS "down"
FROM
  "autogen"."net"
WHERE
  "interface" = 'eth0' AND
    $timeFilter
GROUP BY
  time($__interval)
  fill(null)
```

(The `derivative()` is necessary since `bytes_recv` and `bytes_sent` are accumulating metrics.)

My concern is that the data is not accurate. As a test, I downloaded some very large files (1GB) and confirmed (`ifconfig eth0`) that `RX bytes` was increasing by the expected amount as data was received. However, the graph looks like this:

[image]

There is no change whatsoever to the metrics being recorded. What am I doing wrong?

#### Details

- Host is running Ubuntu Server 16.04
- Telegraf, InfluxDB, and Grafana are running in Docker

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after composing the question, I realized what the problem was. *(cue head on desk)*

Docker provides a virtual ethernet adapter to the container which will only see its own traffic. The solution is to either:

- ...run Telegraf outside of Docker **or**
- ...run the container with the `--net=host` flag